# css html percentage resize image

Tags: html, css, resize

I can't resize an image in css/html. Ican resize it in px but not in %. I already tried min-height, min-widht. Here's my code I can't resize it.

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
}
#top{
    background-color: #53FF40;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
}
#bottom{
    background-color: #FF5757;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
}
.img-yes{
    width: 25%;
    height: 25%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>DoYouLoveDogs</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<body>
<div id="top">
<div class="img-yes">
    <img class="img-yes" src="img/yes.png">
</div>
</div>
<div id="bottom">
</div>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/button.js"></script>
<script>document.write('<script src="http://' + (location.host || 'localhost').split(':')[0] + ':35729/livereload.js?snipver=1"></' + 'script>')</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Can you reproduce the problem in a JSFiddle.net?

Comment: What do you exactly want ? Change the size of the img ? Can you fiddle it

Comment: I see no problem with the code you gave. It resizes perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `display: block`?

```
.img-yes {
    display: block;
    width: 25%;
    height: 25%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
.img-yes
{
width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9yg7b99g/1/)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to set a size in pixels for outer div of image. Then resize image with percentage.

```
.outerdiv{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
}
.img-yes{
  width: 50%;
  height:30%;
}
```

But if you only want to resize image you can only give width in percentage and height will automatically set according to width.

Answer (score 0):

I just copy paste you code in to notepad (change internal css to inline css and change image path) and execute it. It's working properly. When i increase the width, image resize according to width.

Answer (score 0):

```
.img-yes {
    height: 40% !important;
    margin: 5px 28px 22px 82px;
    width: 50% !important;
}
```